# Convert date time (12h) to mysql datetime format in CSV file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, date

I have a CSV file with date time formatted like this:

```
8/2/2012 1:34:01 PM
```

I need to find all the occurrences (probably regex) of such date and convert it (in file) to mysql default datetime format (2012-08-02 13:34:01).

I found that

```
date --date="8/2/2012 1:34:01 PM" +"%F %T"
```

is working properly and I'm getting correct result. The solution would be to find all the occurrences of wrongly formatted date and pass it through this above date function.

Single line from CSV file looks like this:

```
"Data 1","Data 2","Data 3","Data 4","100000000100","100000002263","10/31/2012 10:02:03 AM","1/29/1999 1:54:50 PM","11/6/2012 8:47:01 PM","S"
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Are the date stamps are on separate lines? Can you show a sample of the csv file?

Comment: I edited the post and included single line from CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

is this ok for you?

```
awk -F, -vOFS=','  '{for (i=7;i<=9;i++) {"date --date="$i" +\"%F %T\"" |getline $i;$i="\""$i"\""}}1' file
```

test with that line:

```
kent$  echo '"Data 1","Data 2","Data 3","Data 4","100000000100","100000002263","10/31/2012 10:02:03 AM","1/29/1999 1:54:50 PM","11/6/2012 8:47:01 PM","S"'|awk -F, -vOFS=','  '{for (i=7;i<=9;i++) {"date --date="$i" +\"%F %T\"" |getline $i;$i="\""$i"\""}}1'
"Data 1","Data 2","Data 3","Data 4","100000000100","100000002263","2012-10-31 10:02:03","1999-01-29 13:54:50","2012-11-06 20:47:01","S"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for posting it but this won't work for other files I have (I submitted only part of the line so fixed positions for dates are not good for me). It would be great to have functionality based on regex search. I have this regex if it will help: ([0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} )(PM|AM){0,1}

Comment: ok, then change the for loop to all columns and within it do a if ~ yourREgex check. btw, you should tell your requirement clearly and completely in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If using perl is an option, this should fit your requirement

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my($m, $d, $y, $H, $M, $S, $a) = m!\"(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s+([ap]m)\"!i) {
    $H += 12 if ($a =~ m/pm/i);
    my $dt = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S);
    s!!$dt!;
}
```

Call it with

```
perl -i.bak -p convert.pl csv.txt
```

This will convert the dates to MySQL format. It also creates a backup file `csv.txt.bak`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a tool with a proper CSV parser. Here's a ruby example

```
ruby -e '
  require "csv"
  require "date"

  def format_date(date)
    DateTime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y %r").strftime "%Y-%m-%d %T"
  end

  CSV.foreach ARGV[0] do |row|
    [6,7,8].each {|i| row[i] = format_date row[i]}
    puts CSV.generate_line row, {:force_quotes => true}
  end
' file.csv
```

Given your sample input, this outputs

```
"Data 1","Data 2","Data 3","Data 4","100000000100","100000002263","2012-10-31 10:02:03","1999-01-29 13:54:50","2012-11-06 20:47:01","S"
```